# Loss and gain of region in ATAC seq

Tags: atac-seq

I would like to calculate what is the number of region which is lost or gained between two condition,such as Stem cell vs Leukemic stemcell, atac seq data.

How do I get the information after peak calling such as what tools should i be using ?

As shown in the paper figure 1c I would like to do the same. How do i calculate the gain and loss of peak relative to a condition 
[paper](https://genomebiology.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/s13059-015-0840-9)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you are looking for is "Differential accessibility analysis", you are using ATAC-seq, hence "accessibility". You will need to "call" and then <strike>"normalize"</strike> "count"(*) peaks, after these, you can use `DESeq2` or `edgeR` for the "differential" part.

[Here is a nice Nextflow workflow](https://github.com/nf-core/atacseq) that addresses all of the steps of a differential accessibility analysis of ATAC-Seq data.

* `featureCounts` can be used the identify peaks, see [this](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/103059/) and [this](https://support.bioconductor.org/p/120013/).

Comment: "You will need to "call" and then "normalize" peaks" this part im done. I tried with diffbind, but i was not sure about the result output clearly. Yes will check the nexflow one which i did see but haven;t tried it yet

Comment: I think I was wrong about the normalization part. `DESeq2` and `edgeR` works on raw counts so I believe you will need to use `featureCounts` to get the counts to feed into one of the two DE tools.

Comment: "https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC6527694/#MOESM2" preclisely yes they need raw count and how do i get raw counts from peaks? i ran deseq2 from rna seq data using raw count from bam files , i guess i can't do the same for ATAC seq ,need to get the counts from the peaks isn;t it?

Comment: You can use `featureCounts`, I am editing my answer so as to include two links from the `Bioconductor` forum.

Comment: I manage to get differential peak analysis using deseq2 , now back to my original question now I do have differential peak between various stages how do I define the loss and gain of peaks between stages from deseq2 results or I have to use bedtool or bedops in this case ?

Comment: I don't really understand your question as `DESeq2` output should be giving you what regions are more (or less) open (accessible) in one condition with respect to another (reference) condition. How does the `DESeq2` output look like, can you post the first few lines by editing your question?

Comment: " output should be giving you what regions are more (or less) open (accessible) in one condition with respect to another (reference) condition." yes the deseq2 will show differential accessibility . My question is how do i define loss and gain of peak with respect to reference sample

Comment: updated the question